# If I send bitcoin or some other crypto from my wallet to Binance and I don't see a deposit, what could be going wrong?

Tags: binance

I am still very new to the world of cryptocurrency but as of a couple of years ago I realized its significance and now I am afraid I have a lot of catching up.

Anyway, what happens if I send Bitcoin, Ether, XRP or Dash from my wallet to Binance and I don't see a deposit, what could be going wrong there? How do I troubleshoot something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don’t see your deposit right after you made the transaction, you should wait a little bit, it shouldn’t take so long to have your transaction/s into the blockchain of **x** cryptocurrency.

Transactions can take minutes and even hours in order to go through the verification process which is basically a process for the network to make sure your transaction is legit in all possible ways, after such process your transaction is added to a block and thus to the blockchain for good.

However, there are a few cases where a transaction won’t appear:

1. You put the wrong address
2. number 1

Make sure you put the right information before making a transaction, if it doesn’t appear just give it a little of time and you’ll be fine, but notice that if you put a wrong address or any other parameter required to make a transaction **YOU WONT BE ABLE TO REVERSE/TROUBLESHOOT this event** and *thus, you will loose your money*

*pd: Crypto-exchanges like Binance or coinbase, they all have a certain number of verification in order to have your transaction shown. I don’t know how many binance uses, but I think after 4 verifications (BTC) your transaction will appear on your wallet*, however, such parameters are different among cryptocurrencies, ripple just takes 1 verification and you’ll be all set to spend your money.